# Can I change Origin value of a web socket request and how

Tags: websocket, handshake

I start a server on my computer and load a local html file. When i send web socket request to the server and i check client handshake and the sent handshake from the server the Origin value is different. Can I manipulate this value or set it from somewhere and how?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the origin value being sent by the browser. This is a security feature that allows cross-origin security. The Sec-WebSocket-Origin you are seeing sent back from the server is a feature of the [Hixie 76](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76) version of the protocol that is going away in the [more recent protocol versions](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-12).

Comment: So what can I do in this case? How to establish the connection?

Comment: @Nikolay: If you can't start the connection - are you sending the right handshake key back? In the screenshot you do not seem to send the actual handshake key.

Comment: As @pimvdb mentioned, your problem may be key calculation since your option doesn't show either the third bit of the client key nor your response hash (this has changed in newer revs of the protocol BTW). If you load your page using a normal web server, the origin will be set to the URL used to load the page.